# ios - UITableView Freezing on load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am building a chat application in which I have to to scroll `tableview` to bottom in order to show the most recent message.

What I am doing is, I am scrolling it to visible rect using the following code:

```
- (void)tableViewScrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
   // return;

if (!_tableViewShouldScroll) {
    return;
}

NSInteger numberOfSections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];

if (numberOfSections > 0) {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:numberOfSections - 1];

    if (numberOfRows > 0) {
        CGRect footer =  [self.tableView rectForFooterInSection:numberOfSections - 1];

        [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:footer animated:animated];
    }
}

_tableViewShouldScroll = !_tableViewShouldScroll;
}
```

It scrolls down pretty well but freezes for a second while going through the last cell when the view is loaded for the first time. On successive calls, this method is working fine.

PS. I am calling the scrolling method in `viewdidappear`.

Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is issue with cellForRow method which causes this issue

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the `tableViewScrollToBottomAnimate` in `viewDidAppear`, which was causing the freeze for a fraction of second. I called the method within `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and it worked like a charm.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
   [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
   [self tableViewScrollToBottomAnimated:NO];
}
```